# Android threads are application level or activity level?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Somebody asked me threads like `AsyncTask`, `Thread`, `Runnable` runs on application level or they runs on activity level?

All threads do some work in background and may or may not return output to main thread (activity/fragment).

For example I do `AsyncTask.execute()` and in `onPostExecute()` I will return some data. In between `doInBackground` and  before `onPostExecute` if I/OS kills  activity than `onPostExecute` pass data to activity which is no longer available but inside callback method first I check if activity is running than proceed otherwise do nothing.

It means threads runs on application level am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Threads run on application level.

Activities are simply application components to organize your code.

When an application is killed, the process that runs all your threads is terminated.

For more information:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Almost - but applications do not have 1:1 correspondence to processes.

Comment: I've never heard of an application running more than one process, other than services. But good to know.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can check the definition of these classes.

The Runnable is an interface, defined as below:

```
package java.lang;

public interface Runnable {
    void run();
}
```

The Thread is a class implements the Runnable interface, defined as below:

```
package java.lang;

public class Thread implements Runnable {
    public Thread() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
```

the AsyncTask is an abstract class, defined as below:

```
package android.os;

public abstract class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

    public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> execute(Params... params) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
```

As you said, an Activity is running on the main thread, meantime a Runnable may or may not run on the same thread, because it is only an interface, just a section of code.

the AsyncTask doesn't run on the main thread, it runs on a non-UI thread, so it can do some parallel jobs while the activity is running on the main thread.

All the objects(Activity, AsyncTask, Thread) under the control of the application's life time.

Answer (score 0):

> Threads like AsyncTask, Thread, Runnable runs on application level or they runs on activity level?

They run on `Application level` because an `Activity may be destroyed` while AsyncTask or Thread is downloading a file from `Web`.

And one more thing when doing such an `operation` use `getApplicationContext()` otherwise memory leaks.